# Parsing Json array and object

Tags: android, arrays, json

Can someone give me a good link or help explain the workings of parsing json. I have a array of objects like so........ [{}{}{}]. Im trying to get the value of for example {"name" :"John"....} do I call .get (name) to get value John.or .getString (name) to get value John.

Another thing I came across is on same object there is [{"name":"John", "Eta":"5"}....] I tried to call getstring (ETA) and there was an error can't  .getstring (Eta) on object. Could it have something to do with  the fact that some of the json has something like /"Time":"(0004253200)"/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to explain how to work with JSON in android.

Suppose you have a string like

```
{
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c201",
                "name": "Johnny Depp",
                "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        }
  ]
}
```

Now anything between `{}` is a JSON Object. So this whole string can be converted to one JSON Object.

To do so : `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);`

And anything between `[]` is a JSON Array. In the above example `"contacts"` is a JSONArray.

To get the array `JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");`

Now, suppose you need to get value of name of contact id c201.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str); //Convert whole string to JSONObject.
JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts"); //Get contacts array.
// looping through All Contacts
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i); //Get JSONObject at index i
    if(c.getString("id").equals("c201")){
        return c.getString("name");
    }
}
```

Have a look at [this article](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) for more reading material.

Comment: Thank you between your answer and link I was able to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify() - converts a javascript object into a JSON string.

JSON.parse() - converts a JSON string into a javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

```
String json = "{"name" :"John"}";
JsonObject object = new JsonObiect(json);
String name = object.getString("name");
System.out.println(name);
```